# Random Distribution to fit an Average Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, random, sample

I have a CSV of about 400,000 "scored" rows where I've refit the score to be a linear distribution from 1 to 10, rounded to 5 decimals.  (So from the top, the row[0] column is 10, 9.999997, 9.999995, etc.)

I want to create a script to pull X rows of average score Y from the list.

My expectation is something like a bell curve.  It may be awkward/impossible at low or high values of X and/or Y, but if I pull 10,000 rows of average score 7, there should be a "few" at very low scores, and enough scores to smooth out a distribution.

My first thought was to load the values of row[0] into a list of numbers, force a number-by-number approximation toward a goal of 7, filling in the numbers into another list, then using that list to go back through the CSV and if row[0] is in output_list, out_writer([row]).  But my guesswork stepwise math is probably very inefficient and I don't know what libraries could help me.

Input looks like:

```
Score     Name
10.0      foo
9.99997   bar
9.99995   stuff
9.99992   thing
9.9999    other
```

etc.

I want to be able to input a large variable X and a score Y and output a CSV of X rows from the input file such that their average is Y.  Non-trivially, of course (otherwise, I could just get the X/2 rows on either side of the goal score from the input file!) - a wider distribution would be preferred.

Ideally, I would find a solution that allows for asymmetric distributions. For example, if I wanted 100 numbers averaging to 9.0, I would expect about twenty numbers above 9.0 to counter a 1.0. Surely that could get messy, but I would also expect a 1.0 to be 1/20th as likely.

Comment: Can you create a small sample input and example output for this exercise? My guess is there's some way to just "magic" this in numpy but I'm not familiar with it at all.

Comment: Probably want something like [`numpy.random.normal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). Draw random samples and take the nearest one from your dataset.

Comment: That does look like what I want.  It doesn't have a min and max - my worry is that it will always draw symmetrical curves.  So if I want an average of 7, will I be lopping off everything under 4? (Standard Deviation of (10-X)/3, ending at +-3.0 for 4 - 10?)  How do I adapt numpy.random.normal to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [`scipy.stats.truncnorm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html), seems like it would fit the bill. Writing a small wrapper to convert it from a standard normal curve and it works quite well.

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

def my_norm(start, end, mean=0, sdev=1, size=None):
    a = (start - mean)/sdev
    b = (end - mean)/sdev
    rv = truncnorm(a, b)
    return rv.rvs(size)*sdev + mean
```

Play around with the standard deviations (`sdev`) a bit. 1/3 the distance from the closest edge seems it would be a safe bet (ie if Y==8 then sdev=(10-8)/3).

Comment: This works.  Easy to run out the box and very fast.  Ideally, I would find a solution that allows for asymmetric distributions.  For example, if I wanted 100 numbers averaging to 9.0, I would expect about twenty numbers above 9.0 to counter a 1.0.  Surely that could get messy, but I would also expect a 1.0 to be 1/20th as likely.